# Would the Exodus generation not have entered Canaan/spent years in the desert irrespective of sin?

Tags: rambam, dor-hamidbar, meraglim-spies, avraham-ibn-ezra, slave-mentality

[R Avraham ibn Ezra](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ibn_Ezra_Second_Commentary/Shemot/14.13#m4e0n6) and [Rambam](https://library.alhatorah.org/?r1=Moreh_Nevukhim_3:32) both posit that the Israelite slaves that left Egypt were not upto the task of war and needed to die out and be replaced with more courageous progeny (ibn Ezra) and/or get toughened up by rugged desert living (Rambam).

The Torah is fairly explicit ([Bamidbar 14](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Tanakh/Bemidbar/14.1#m4e2n6)) that had the Israelites not sinned in believing the negative report regarding Canaan they wouldn't have died out or tarried in the midbar and would have proceeded to the promised land without delay.

How does that fit it in with the above mentioned rishonim's theory?

Comment: Doesn't what they did wrong, illustrate how they needed to grow?

Comment: @MichoelR It presumably does however the rishonim mentioned seem to indicate that it needed to happen due to their conditioning regardless of sin which seems to contravene what is written in the Torah

Comment: I don't really see that implication from the Rishonim. Maybe bring evidence.

Comment: @MichoelR I linked to the relevant pieces but here's the language from ibn Ezra: והשם לבדו, כי הוא עושה גדולות, לו נתכנו עלילות, סבב שמתו כל העם היוצא ממצרים הזכרים, אין בהם כח להלחם בכנענים, עד שקם דור המדבר, שלא ראו גלות והיתה להם נפש גבוהה and Rambam: וכמו שהיה מחכמת האלוה להסב אותם במדבר עד שילמדו גבורה

Comment: Had the *benei yisrael* not sinned they would not have been subject to this natural conjugation of emotional experience.

Comment: I don't have a source, but this is how I see it: Had the nation rejected the negative report and chosen to trust that God is fully allied with them in the mission of conquering the Land then this would have demonstrated the existence of a courage and fortitude forged independent of experience. Since they did not demonstrate such courage and fortitude, it had to be forged by circumstance in order to shape them into the type of people psychologically prepared to enter the Land with righteous might. I think this can be expanded, but that is the main idea (IMHO).

Comment: @Deuteronomy Interesting take. So in your thinking it isnt a classic direct cause and effect type of punishment but rather them showing that they hadnt (superhumanly) transcended their natural conditioning with the status quo plan still nec.. Nice idea

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that I wouldn't still characterize it as "cause/effect" just not in the simplistic/primitive sense of press the wrong button or pulling the wrong lever and getting a klop.. more in the vein of naturalistic consequence. But yes, they failed to transcend their conditioning - doing so would have been an extraordinary feat of self-discipline and internalization of high level concepts. Sadly they weren't able to rise to the occasion, and succumbed to the mental habits they had acquired which in turn meant having to go the difficult/long way in order to shed that mindset

Comment: @Deuteronomy Not sure Id agree with your characterization. These rishonim say that given their past they weren't the right people for the job. Not extraordinarily rising above that doesn't seem to fall under the "natural consequence" branch of "cause & effect" either but rather is an outgrowth of their servitude in mitzrayim. It is your idea tho 

Comment: Extraordinary (or what you deem "superhuman") growth within a short span can occur within a naturalistic framework. What would have been extraordinary about it would have been them overcoming the momentum of their mindset cultivated over generations of servitude. A high order, no doubt. Nevertheless, possible.

Comment: Anshe segulah overcome with great determination their inner struggles, and by then we certainly had the model of the patriarchs on that point. Ultimately, however they didn’t succeed in “getting over their past” and insofar as they failed on that front, they weren't suited for the job. Accordingly, it may properly be said “why wasn’t that generation fit to enter the land? Because they had a slave mentality, i.e. they failed to shed a mindset that was detrimental to national success in the form of conquest” Anyway, just my 2¢ 